# Table Join in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have something like two table User and Transaction. A user might have multiple transaction. But I need to join the User Table and the last transaction from Transaction table.

As of now what I did is I fetched the User data and along with it came the entire Transaction as a List but I need to limit the transaction to last 1 or final transaction only. This is based on the max value of id. It is getting slow when a lazy fetch is being fetched for a user with lots of transactions. how do I fix this to get the last transaction only.

As usual I have

```
User{

    Blah blah;
    List<Transaction> transaction;

}
```

and am doing

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(User.Class);
// Other Criteria applied here
criteria.list;
```

Comment: Did you try session.createFilter method? You can get transaction's list ordered by id desc and than set max results to 1 using [setMaxResults(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#setMaxResults(int))

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to join from Child to Parent:

```
select t 
from Transaction t
inner join fetch t.user u
where t.id = ( select max(id) from Transaction )
```

Hibernate cannot return partial one(many)-to-many collections. You always get all associated children, because those are going to be managed as well.

Selecting the Child and fetching the Parent is much more appropriate for this task.

Comment: I've done exactly what you said but now I need a right join for User as there might be Users without Transactions. How do I do that.

Comment: You can either issue a second query like: "select u from User where u.transactions is empty" or select all users and all their transactions, like: "select u from user left join u.transactions" and transform the results to a DTO list where you pair the User with his last transaction.

Answer (score 0):

This should be done with SQL instead of criteria.

`select {u.*}, {t.*} from user as u inner join (select user_id, max(id) as max_t_id from transaction group by user_id) on u.id = user_id inner join transaction as t on t.id = max_t_id`

Read this doc: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html

You should `setEntity("u", User.class)` and `setEntity("t", Transaction.class)`.

From the list method, you will get a list of Object[]'s on which first item is user and second its last transaction. The users will have their complete list of transactions as collection, but this can be configured to be lazily loaded.